# A label in TikZ/PGFplots not showing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have looked at similar questions but have not found the answer.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.2]
  \begin{axis}[axis line style={thick}, 
      axis x label/.style={at{(ticklabel cs:0.1)}},
      axis y label/.style={at{(ticklabel cs:0.1)}},
      %view={170}{20},
      view={45}{45},
      %axis equal,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-2,xmax=2,
      ymin=-2,ymax=2,
      zmin=0,zmax=12.56,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      xtick distance=1.0,
      ytick distance=1.0,
      ztick distance=4.0,
      %colormap/bone,
      xlabel=$x$,
      xlabel=$y$,
      zlabel=$z$,
      trig format plots=rad,
      clip=false
    ]
    \addplot3 [ surf, domain=0:2, domain y=0:12.56,
      samples=70, samples y=70,
      variable=\u, variable y=\v,
    point meta=u*v, opacity=0.4 ]
    ({u*cos(v)},
    {u*sin(v)},
  {v});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, is the picture:

[image: helix3d]

Please observe that the $x$ label is not showing (also I think $x$ is $y$ but $y$ is $x$ but that is a different issue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
      xlabel=$x$,
      xlabel=$y$,  % <--- here is eror
      zlabel=$z$,
```

you should wrote

```
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      zlabel=$z$,
```

Your MWE is not compilable. You have some error in it, consequently I can't provide image generated by your MWE.

Comment: I am sorry for the stupid error. I appreciate @Zarko  's  help.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, own typing errors as the most difficult to find yourself. well, you can accept my answer :-). Please, see why your MWE doesn't work. I like to test your complete MWE. Something is wrong with your function (error: *you need wizard to enlarge me*).

Comment: @Zaiko : Yes, finding our own errors is hard. I spent two hours fighting this before posting the question to you. I tried "everything possible" without success. I already accepted your answer (thanks again). The code should work as it is posted, except for the " [![helix3d][1]][1] " at the end. That was introduce by StackExchange software, that is no mine.  I am using: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, I use MIkTeX (pdfTeX  3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)  (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.17) .  Even after removin misplaced image, I cant compile your MWE. Something in `\addplot3` function is wrong.

Comment: I believe you  use Windows. I am in Ubuntu. I have seen codes that compile well in one system but do not in another. Here is the last few lines of my log file: Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
 on input linetexlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on parkinglot.pdf (1 page, 202806 bytes).
Transcript written on parkinglot.log.